# Lit element innerHTML showing incorrect value

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit

When using an on click event to get the value of clicked element, using `.innerHTML` it returns the lit element ID too:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  value=${item.value}
  .checked=${item.checked}
  @click=${this.toggleRadioCheck}
>

toggleRadioCheck(e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerHTML); // Result: <!--?lit$5487646469$-->Input One
  console.log(e.target.value); // Result: Input One
}
```

As you can see using `e.target.value` is returning the correct value but using `e.target.innerHTML` picks up the LIT ID too. When lit components are rendered in shadow DOM LIT attaches a commented ID associated to the component, but hoping there was a way to use `innerHTML` to get the value.

How can avoid returning the ID generated by LIT. This:

Comment: Why do you need to specifically use `.innerHTML`? It seems better to grab a specific value. `.innerText` or `.textContent` are alternatives that will not show the comment nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why exactly you don't want to use the value, because that would be the correct way in this example.
I am using the following function when I write snapshot tests to remove those comments:

```
export const cleanHTML = (el: Element): string => {
  const innerHTML = el.shadowRoot!.innerHTML;
  return innerHTML.replace(/<!--([\s\S]*?)-->/g, '');
};
```

So the call would be in your example:

```
console.log(cleanHTML(e.target));
```